# VBA Table For Each If Then Loop - text repeat

Tags: vba, if-statement, foreach

I need a code that looks through a column in a table and if the text there is a certain string, then new text needs to be entered in another column.

So, review column A (Service Sub Type), enter text in column B (Product Category) based on column A. This is what I have so far.

```
Dim productsubtype As Range

For Each productsubtype In Range("RawData[Service Sub Type]")
    If productsubtype.Value = "Training" Then
    Range("RawData[Product Category]").Value = "Education"

    End If

Next productsubtype
```

But what's happening is that it is just populating all of column B with "Education", regardless of what is in column A. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Range("RawData[Product Category]")` refers to the entire column. If you already know the columns, I'd just use `productsubtype.Offset(,1).Value = "Education"`.

Comment: Why can't this be an `IF` formula in the `[Product Category]` column? `=IF([Service Sub Type]="Training", "Education", "???")`?

Comment: Or better, have another table  mapping "Service Sub Type" to "Product Category", and have that other column be just a lookup formula.

Comment: @BigBen I don't know why, but doing that completely fixed my problem. Two days of research... THANK YOU!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon This is a really small part of a huge If-Then sequence (the spreadsheet I'm implementing this in is 20,000+ rows, so a workbook formula would have been too difficult to manage.

Comment: "a huge if-then sequence" over the same expression over and over, smells very, very much like a job for a very easy-to-manage lookup table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mathieu suggested, you should use a lookup table, rather than a long if statement if at all possible.

Probably is not always as simple `if this then that`, however you should be able to eliminate most of these if statements with a lookup table, and have some if statements only for what it really matters.

[image]

Having said that, using your example and with an added lookup table (in my example I've named that `lookupTable`), this should give you a starting point:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub lookupValues()

Dim arrData As Variant: arrData = Range("RawData") 'declare and allocate your table to an array
Dim arrLookup As Variant: arrLookup = Range("lookupTable") 'declare and allocate your lookup table to an array
Dim R As Long, X As Long

For R = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData) 'for each row in your data
    For X = LBound(arrLookup) To UBound(arrLookup) 'for each row in the lookup table
        If arrData(R, 1) = arrLookup(X, 1) Then 'if there is a match
            arrData(R, 2) = arrLookup(X, 2) 'allocate the value to the array
            Exit For 'value found, check next
        End If
    Next X
Next R

Range("RawData") = arrData 'put the values back into the table

End Sub
```